# Conversion to late binding

Tags: excel, vba

I have a piece of code in excel that modifies an embedded word document (displayed as icon) and saves it to a path.
I have to convert it to late binding because of compatibility issues. How do i do it? What do I have to change?
here is part of my code, as an example

```
Function Sport()

Dim wd As Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document

Dim ole As OLEObject
Dim EmbededFile As String

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet with the embedded file")

' Change to suit your needs, or build with code
EmbededFile = ThisWorkbook.path & "\Stuff.doc"

Set ole = ws.OLEObjects("Object")
ole.Activate
'ole.Verb Verb:=xlOpen
Set wd = ole.Object.Application
With wd.ActiveDocument
    .SaveAs EmbededFile, Word.wdFormatDocumentDefault
    .Close
End With
Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(EmbededFile)

'' do stuff


wd.Activate
doc.Close
wd.Quit

Sport = 3
End Function
```

thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Dim wd As Word.Application -> Dim wd As Object 
... etc ...

Comment: Can you elaborate on *compatibility issues*?  Have you run into issues caused by different users running different versions of Word?

Comment: Yes I used Word object library 15.0 in Excel 2016 and it didn't work in Excel 2003 (the latest Obj Lib was 11.0). It said missing Word object library 15.0

Comment: Note that the 2003 and 2016 object models are potentially quite different; if your code uses features that didn't exist in the 2003 object model, expect things to blow up at run-time with error 438 "Object doesn't support this property or method". Otherwise, just remove the reference, make sure you have `Option Explicit` at the top of every single module, and replace Word types with `Object`, remove all `Word` qualifiers, and define your own constants (e.g. `wsFormatDocumentDefault`) - rinse & repeat until the project compiles again (Alt+D,ENTER). Harder if you don't have `Option Explicit` on.

Comment: how do I redefine the `wsFormatDocumentDefault` as constant?
and what do I substitute `Word` with?
(sorry I'm really ignorant in vba)